# Can thread wake up when receiving condition signal but can't get mutex lock at the same time

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I write a program for testing pthread_cond_signal. Firstly, one thread blocks in pthread_cond_wait because condition is false. Then the main thread fetchs the mutex, and try to make blocked thread wake up. But the program receives SIGSEGV. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct condTest_s  condTest_t;
struct condTest_s {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
};

condTest_t test; // global variable

/* newly created thread */
void *thread1(void *arg)
{
    printf("thread1 starts \n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&test.mutex); // get lock

    /* Sorry, I made a editing mistake the next sentence and have modified.
     * Previous my code is pthread_cond_wait(&test.cond);  
     */
    pthread_cond_wait(&test.cond, &test.mutex); 

    printf("hello\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&test.mutex); // unlock

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    void *ret;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&test.mutex, NULL) != 0) { // initialize mutex

    /* error */
    exit(2);
    }

    if (pthread_cond_init(&test.cond, NULL) != 0) {// initialize condtion variable

    /* error */
    exit(2);
    }

    if (pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread1, NULL) != 0) {

    /* creation error*/
    exit(2);
   }

    /* wait for newly created thread run first */
    printf("sleep 1\n");
    sleep(3);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&test.mutex); // get lock
    pthread_cond_signal(&test.cond);

    /* sleep to test whether blocked thread would wake up 
     * when condition becomes true, but mutex is locked 
     */
    printf("sleep 2\n");
    sleep(3);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&test.mutex); // unlock
    pthread_join(tid, (void **)&ret);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

- I try `strace ./a.out`, output:
   futex(0x7f24e86419e0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable+++    
  +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
- I modified the code to make it call pthread_cond_wait() correctly. And the output is what it should be. No SIGSEGV again. Can this program prove that if thread is blocked in pthread_cond_wait(), it would wake up only when both pthread_cond_signal(or pthread_cond_broadcast) is called and obtains mutex lock, without getting mutex lock it wolud block like calling pthread_mutex_lock()???

Comment: `conditional locks` always require a lock to be acquired after being signaled. The lock is automatically and atomically acquired right before the `pthread_cond_wait()` returns. The problem in your case is that you're not passing the lock handler to the `pthread_cond_wait()` along with the `conditional mutex`.

Comment: So what would happen if the mutex has been locked by another thread?

Comment: That's a synchronization issue. You need to account for that and implement a thread synchronization mechanism to prevent deadlocks.

Comment: But I doubt whether only one mutex can cause deadlocks.

Comment: That will depend on the implementation. Your example does not seem to implement any kind of synchronization. You're using sleep()s, but nothing guarantees you that the newly created thread was already born to receive the conditional signal.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html How did your example compile?

Comment: Please rework this as a [_minimal, complete, and verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that passes your compiler's `-Wall` check.

Comment: @pilcrow Thanks! I've corrected, but the gcc didn't report an error. And the program outputs as I want. No SIGSEGV

Comment: Take compiler warnings serious. Fix the code until they are gone.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your code to run by adding

```
#include <pthread.h>
```

and then adding the `&test.mutex` argument to the `pthread_cond_wait` function.

```
pthread_cond_wait(&test.cond, &test.mutex);
```